# Reference Qualtrics embedded data field containing dot (.) character

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

When importing fields from a Contacts List, corresponding embedded data fields include dots (`.`).   For example, here's the name of one embedded data that gets automatically created on Contact List import:

```
result.elements.0.embeddedData.V1
```

In my survey, I want to access the value stored in this embedded data field.  But the `getEmbeddedData()` javascript method that Qualtrics provides apparently doesn't like dots.
For a simpler example, I shortened the above embedded data name to `V.1`:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('V.1'); // returns null
```

and a null value is returned.

If I change the embedded data field name to `V1` (no `.`), then the method returns the correct value:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('V1'); # returns correct value
```

In the case where there's a dot in the name, I tried escaping with `\\` and `\`, like: `getEmbeddedData('V\\.1')`, but both of those escape styles don't work - `null` is returned.

There is another syntax to access embedded data with javascript - the `"${e://Field/myfield}"` approach - but I need to be able to set the last character (i.e. the number after `V`) dynamically, and this method doesn't allow for that.  Specifically, for embedded data `V1`:

```
var ix = 1;
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData('V'+ix); <-- this works
"${e://Field/V"+ix+"}"; <-- this doesn't work
```

I have over 1000 fields that get imported from this contact list, so I don't want to rename each one by hand to remove the dots.  It seems weird that Qualtrics would pick this naming schema as an import default if it breaks one of its own methods - am I doing something wrong here?  Is there an alternate syntax I can use?

Answer (score 1):

I answered your related question on the Qualtrics Community. You can't do `"${e://Field/V"+ix+"}"` because pipes are resolved on the server before the page is sent to the browser.

When a web service returns json or xml, by default Qualtrics uses a dot for each level in structure. You can override this by changing the embedded variables (on the left in the web service block) to names without dots.

Another alternative would be to write your own web service script that calls the Qualtrics API, then puts the results in a flat json structure before returning them to your survey.

**Update based on comments below**

Automatically renaming embedded variables returned from a web service call - I think the only way to do that is my alternative suggestion - write your own web service script that converts the info returned from the api and renames the variables putting them in a one dimensional associative array, then convert that array to json.

Qualtrics Question API - getEmbeddedData() has been removed from the documentation. I don't know why, and would have to ask Qualtrics Support. For now, it still works. So, if you need to construct embedded variable names with a dot dynamically, you could create your own function based off getEmbeddedData().  Use your browser's developer tools to see what it does.

I've found addEmbeddedData() to be useless in actual practice.  setEmbeddedData() works whether the embedded data field is defined in the survey flow or not. If it is defined in the survey flow, it gets saved to the response data.  If it is not defined in the survey flow, it can be referenced throughout the current survey response, but it won't be saved in the response data.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this answer.  Yes, I have seen a couple of your other SO answers about the pipes being resolved on the server - I was just noting that I know that doesn't work here.  The main question I have is how to escape the `.` characters.  I found a few workarounds already to actually achieve the end goal I had, these are also good ideas you here.  But this question is mainly about finding the proper escape syntax to call these ED fields correctly.  Any ideas there?

Comment: Only one, and its not pretty. Interestingly, getEmbeddedData isn't even included in the Question API documentation anymore (https://co1.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/QuestionAPI/classes/Qualtrics%20JavaScript%20Question%20API.html). My one idea is to find the Qualtrics getEmbeddedData JS using developer tools, then use it as the basis to write your own getEmbeddedData function.

Comment: Interesting - I wonder if the method is deprecated?  If so that'd be a shame, as that's the only way I've been able to get around the inability to make client-side updates to the `${e://Field/...}` syntax.  (Also slightly unrelated: the `setEmbeddedData()` API docstring now says "Sets embedded data to the page, or adds it if the ED key is not on the page already"...that's also new to me, I thought the ED key already had to be set for that to work.)

Comment: That's a good (although arduous) idea re rewriting `getEmbeddedData()`.  Can you update your answer to suggest that and also note that the method is no longer in the docs?  Also, re your suggestion about renaming the embedded variable names, is there any way to do that programmatically?  (In my original post I mentioned I had about 1000 ED fields and didn't want to rename by hand.)  None of these points are quite an actual answer to the question, but happy to upvote if you can swap out the current answer for some of what we've got here in the comments.  Thanks!