# Read embedded data that starts with numbers?

Tags: qualtrics

I have embedded data that I have imported into Qualtrics use a web service block. The data comes from a .json file and reads something like 0.male, 1.male, 2.male, etc.

I have been trying to read this into my survey using the Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData method but without luck.

I'm trying to do something that takes the form.

let n = 2
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.getEmbeddedData(n + ".male")
but this has been returning a NULL result. Is it possible to read embedded data that starts with a number?

Also see:

https://community.qualtrics.com/XMcommunity/discussion/15991/read-in-embedded-variables-using-a-loop#latest

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the number, it is the dot. getEmbeddedData() doesn't work when the name contains a dot. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51802695/4434072 for possible alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look. I found this after posting a question. How feasible do you think it is to write my own function?

Comment: I think it is doable, but rather difficult.  It would be easier to rename the variables in the webservice block (map the returned fields to new embedded data names). Another way is to use a loop & merge block. Pipe the embedded data fields into the loop & merge setup.